# What's the difference between Resource and Content in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I recently learned that Embedded Resource means that assets are saved to an external .resx file.

Setting assets to Resource makes them join the .exe file simply.

Now, I'm confused of when to use Content and Resource.

Any info?

Comment: Embedded resources, as the name imply, are embedded in the executable file, not "saved to an external .resx file"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Resource : Embeds resource into the
>   assembly (or culture specific
>   satellite assembly)
>
> Content : this leaves resource as
>   loose file and upon compilation this
>   resource information is not embedded
>   to assembly. Instead, it adds custom
>   attribute to the assembly
>   (AssemblyAssociatedContentFile) which
>   records the existence and relative
>   location of file.
>   It is also possible
>   to access the resource file without
>   adding into the project. However, with
>   this approach management of resource
>   file becomes bit difficult. However,
>   **this approach is useful if resource
>   file is generated dynamically using
>   some runtime information. In such a
>   case, resource file will not be
>   available at compile time so can not
>   be added to project.**

Source: [Resources in WPF](http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/resources-in-wpf-i-binary-resources/).