# Copy files to output directory using csproj dotnetcore

Tags: c#, .net-core

So my issue is pretty simple. I have some files that I want to be copied to the build output directory whether it is a debug build or a release publish. All of the information I can find is about the old json config approach. Anyone have an example using the csproj with dotnetcore?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to achieve your goals, depending on what your needs are.

The easiest approach is setting the metadata (`CopyToOutputDirectory` / `CopyToPublishDirectory`) items conditionally (assuming `.txt` being a `None` item instead of `Content`, if it doesn't work, try `<Content>` instead):

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <None Update="foo.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If more control is required, the most versatile approach is to add custom targets that hook into the build process in the csproj file:

```xml
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="foo.txt" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CopyCustomContentOnPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="foo.txt" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
</Target>
```

This copies a file to the respective directories. For more options for the `<Copy>` task, see [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task). To limit this to certain configurations, you can use a `Condition` attribute:

```xml
<Target … Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
```

This `Condition` attribute can be applied both on the `<Target>` element or on task elements like `<Copy>`.

Comment: How would i apply 'DestinationFolder' to <Reference> items, or is it event possible, there's not much in the docs that i can find. I don't want all my assemblies at the root level and would prefer them to be in their own folder.

Comment: You can set `DestinationSubDirectory="subdir\"` metadata on `Reference` items directly. However this means you need to implement assembly resolution yourself ([AssemblyResolve event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: How can I copy parent folder that contains some dlls in respective folders. I want to make them available in the output published path so that after build these folders r available for my application at run time, as I load these dlls as plugins at startup. I am using rider on mac

Comment: Warning, if you are using Azure Pipelines and the files to be copied do not exist except from a PreBuild step in the same `.csproj` file.  You will run into a chicken-and-egg problem where the build agent "misses" the files.  It may be related to the warning they provide during the build step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

Answer (score 168):

While this helped me get my issue sorted, it didn't work for all files in a sub-directory. I also used `Content Include` rather than `Content Update`.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="layouts\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>  
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Every other permutation of all of the other answers/suggestions failed to work for me.  Not even a mention of the file in verbose build output.  But your suggestion here worked.

Comment: And if you want to include intermediate subfolders use `<Content Include="layouts\**\*.*">`

Comment: When using the Web SDK (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`) it wont allow you to use `Include=` because it is already seems to implicitly specify that within the SDK. I had to use `Update=` to get it to build and include my additional files.

Comment: Nice, thanks.. But how to copy only the content of the folder to the output directory not the folder itself. The expression `assets\*.*` should assume it. But it copies the complete assets folder. So I have `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/assets/...` But I want the files of the assets folder to the root directory of the output. `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/...`.

Comment: I found a solution:
```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssetsSourceFiles Include="assets/**/*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(AssetsSourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```
(see my answer for a better code format.)

Comment: Not sure why, but I had to use `<None Update="layouts\*.*>` to get mine to work

Answer (score 51):

Assuming you have an `assets` folder in your root directory. You can name it as you want. This is just an example:

**your-project.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssetsSourceFiles Include="assets/**/*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(AssetsSourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

this copies only the content of the `assets` folder to the output root without wrapping it into the `assets` folder. But if you want to copy with the folder itself, you can use the following code:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="assets\**\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Excellent, I was missing the assets\**\*.* ... the two wildcards to specify depth. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Place this in your .csproj file, replacing nlog.config with the desired file path.  Then simply save it and build your project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="Nlog.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to copy subdirectories.

Answer (score 8):

I had the requirement for a selection of HTML templates to be consumable both client-side and server-side (Handlebars js)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\html-templates\**\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 7):

For example, you have file named **test.txt**. To set **Copy always** to this file you need to add this section to your .csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="test.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

This will copy full directory into subdirectory with proper names.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content 
      Include="..\libs\x64\**\*.*"
      CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"
      TargetPath="x64\%(Filename)%(Extension)"
    />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to force copy of a specific NuGet package into an ASP.NET Core project (2.2), add at the end of your csproj:

```xml
<!-- Force copy MathNet because we need it in compilation -->
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll'))" />
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       <TargetPath>MathNet.Numerics.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Xml" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Xml" /S /F /I /R /Y</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)MyXml.xml" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Xml"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Ideally use a <Copy> task to make it cross platform.

Comment: copy sometimes may fail whole building process. e..g because of race conditions. imagine you have a `class library` with a file which you need to put into `outdir` and it is referenced by many projects. solution is build by `msbuild` with `-maxCpuCount` option - like building in parallel. and it turns out that several thread try to copy the same file via copy target and it fails. i switched to `xcopy\copy` and the problem gone

Comment: Did you add the Copy task to all projects? Perhaps via Directory.Build.props? You can set that to run on a single project by conditioning it only to the project that you expect to make the copy (e.g: The first project to build). Those that depend on that output won't run in parallel

Comment: No, the copy task is in single project, which owns the file. Could you please share what do you mean by to run a single project by conditioning it ...

Comment: Like <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ProjectName)' == 'MyProject'">