# VS Code: How to copy files to output directory depending on build configurations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I just started a new project in VS Code (C#, .NET Core). Anyways, I want to be able to copy files from within my project directory to the output directory like I can in visual studio. But I also want to copy specific files depending on whether or not I'm building for 32 or 64 bit.

I've looked around but so far all I've learnt how to do is copy files regardless of my build configurations.

Comment: Right Click on your Solution ==> Properties ==> Build ==> Platform Target, That how you'd know

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I'm not using visual studio.

Comment: Did you give this post a try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374074/copy-files-to-output-directory-using-csproj-dotnetcore

Comment: @Daniel That was the first post I found, however it doesn't tell me how to handle different architectures.

Comment: Try `File.Copy(sourcePath, C:\File.txt);` And to get your Project directory, use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: Thanks for posting your first question. For future reference, it's worth reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which advises to post in your question what your research is and why it did not work for you, since it wastes the time of the people volunteering their time to answer your question.

Comment: @Richardissimo I've mentioned what research I've found and why it doesn't work for me already. I said that I know how to copy files using VS Code, but not how to copy files depending on the build configurations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x86'  Or '$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x64'">
    <None Update="foo.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x64'">
    <None Update="foo.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

Steps:

1. Create a console app by running `dotnet new console`
2. Add foo.txt and foo.xml to the project folder.
3. Edit the `.csproj`  file as above.
4. Build the project with multiple configurations. 
   `dotnet build -c Release -r win-x86`
5. **`foo.xml` is copied only for a `x-64` build whereas `foo.txt` is copied for both [RID's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)**

[image: Output folder]