# Visual Studio Code does not copy nlog.config

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nlog

How can I include file as resource output from Visual Studio Code?
I want nlog.config to be copied to the output directory.

This is ASP.NET Core Web API project.

In VS 2017 this would be: "Build Action: Content" option in the properties menu.

Comment: `<Content …>` is fine for this, yeah. Unfortunately, you don’t get tooling in Visual Studio Code for this, so you have to know how to modify your project file for this.

Comment: maybe it's a good idea to add your answer, as answer to stackoverflow :) (and accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually edit project and add nlog settings.

In VS 2017 this can be done through the UI:
- "Build Action: Content" option in the properties menu of the nlog.config.

Final version of the project in VS Code:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems> //added
  </PropertyGroup>

  //commented
  <!-- <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup> -->

  //added
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="nlog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may need the `defaultContentItems` to handle the default loading. And another way to copy the config file is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378406/15237039