# How to Add Static Files and Folders to Azure Function Deployment in Azure

Tags: azure, static-files, azure-function-app

I using an Azure function app to call the API from Asp.Net core application, in azure functions I am handling statics folders and files. After deployed in Azure there is no folders and files in app service editor screen.

How can I include the files and folders at the time of deployment? Is there any possibilities to add wwwroot folder like we are having in Asp.Net core application?

Comment: are you copying your files on build? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374074/copy-files-to-output-directory-using-csproj-dotnetcore

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your `Function App` localy it will deploy to Azure portal only files from your local `/bin` folder and `host.json`. So, you won't have an ability to edit your code from the portal.

If you're starting your `Function App` from scratch on the portal, you can add folders and files to your App in such a way:

- `Azure Function app -> Development Tools section -> Advanced Tools`, then click on the `Go` button on the Advanced Tools window. Now you are able to see `Debug console` DropDown on the top of the page, select the `CMD` option from that dropdown. Click on the `Site` folder.There are two ways of adding files/folders: 1. by clicking `+` near the folder name  2. using powershell window that you have below (run something like `md [folderName]`).
- `Azure Function app -> Development Tools section -> App Service Editor (Preview)`, then use context menu (*by clicking right mouse button*) to add files/folders in a folder tree of your App.