# How can I wrap C# DLLs into a NuGet package on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, dll, nuget-package

On Ubuntu I'd like to wrap a few C# DLL files into a NuGet package. On Windows one would use the [NuGet package explorer or `nuget.exe` + manually edited `*.csproj.nuspec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls). In summary when manually editing the `*.nuspec` file one may add DLLs via the `<files>` section:

```
<files>
   <file src="some\Path\YourDll.dll" target="lib"></file>
</files>
```

On Ubuntu I'd like to use `dotnet pack` instead. However it seems like it's not able to operate on a `*.csproj.nuspec` file:

```
Usage: dotnet pack [options] <PROJECT | SOLUTION>

Arguments:
  <PROJECT | SOLUTION>   The project or solution file to operate on. If a file is not specified, the command will search the current directory for one.

Options:
  -h, --help                            Show command line help.
  -o, --output <OUTPUT_DIR>             The output directory to place built packages in.
  --no-build                            Do not build the project before packing. Implies --no-restore.
  --include-symbols                     Include packages with symbols in addition to regular packages in output directory.
  --include-source                      Include PDBs and source files. Source files go into the 'src' folder in the resulting nuget package.
  -c, --configuration <CONFIGURATION>   The configuration to use for building the package. The default for most projects is 'Debug'.
  --version-suffix <VERSION_SUFFIX>     Set the value of the $(VersionSuffix) property to use when building the project.
  -s, --serviceable                     Set the serviceable flag in the package. See https://aka.ms/nupkgservicing for more information.
  --nologo                              Do not display the startup banner or the copyright message.
  --interactive                         Allows the command to stop and wait for user input or action (for example to complete authentication).
  --no-restore                          Do not restore the project before building.
  -v, --verbosity <LEVEL>               Set the MSBuild verbosity level. Allowed values are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic].
  --runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>        The target runtime to restore packages for.
  --no-dependencies                     Do not restore project-to-project references and only restore the specified project.
  --force                               Force all dependencies to be resolved even if the last restore was successful.
                                        This is equivalent to deleting project.assets.json.
```

Can I wrap C# DLLs into a NuGet package on Ubuntu using the `dotnet` CLI? Or do I have to use the `nuget` CLI (`apt-get install nuget`) instead with the approach like on Windows?

Comment: What is the `*.csproj.nuspec` file? Aren't they two different files?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, of course that are separate files. In `*.csproj.nuspec` one can define DLLs to include into a nuget package. The question is if this is possible via `*.csproj` as well. Then I could use `dotnet pack`. Otherwise I'd probably have to use `nuget` instead.

Comment: You can define a properties directly in `.cspoj` file, as described here [Create and publish a package (dotnet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli)

Comment: Do you mean via `<ItemGroup>`?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this into the .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="some.dll" PackageCopyToOutput="true">
        <pack>true</pack>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: I'm experimenting with `<Content Include="lib\net5.0\Some.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>`. What's the difference?

Comment: That works? I's been a while, took this from an older project that I knew worked :-). I had quiet a bit of trouble getting it to work, providing this as example hopefully it saves you some time .

Comment: There are a lot of examples in github which use this. I assume it works but I don't know yet.

Comment: It seems like `CopyToOutputDirectory` is usually needed only if one want's to provide [static files and the like as part of the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374074/copy-files-to-output-directory-using-csproj-dotnetcore).