# load a relative file in streamReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, netcoreapp3.1

I have a json file  I am trying to read via a `StreamReader`. The json is in the same directory as my code. However, any method for loading the file (`GetFullPath()`, `GetDirectoryName()`, etc) is always looking in the `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` directory, where it obviously is not.  I have tried all the different versions

I think that has more to do with an issue with netcoreapp than anything else. How do I get it to just load the file in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Don't include a path at all. That will use the current directory, which by default is the directory of the executable file. I mention this for completeness, but it probably won't work, because your executable is not in the same folder as your code!

Option 2: Look for the file in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. The properties for the file there will include an option to `Copy to Output Directory` that is probably currently set to `Do not copy`. You want this to be `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. Then, when you build your project, it will place the file in the `Debug` or `Release` folder with your program.

Comment: This was my big miss!  Its been so long since I have had to do this, I forgot about copying to output.  C# really needs to have better native support of json, that would be the best fix!

Comment: You have three different major options on NuGet for loading and writing JSON.

Comment: You have one you suggest?  I ask, cause most of the json Schema validators out there still you streamReaders as part off all their examples.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your project the compiled code is copied to the `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` directory. The application than runs from there. So the 'problem' you are referring to is actually the expected behaviour.

You can either:

- Manually copy the file to the build folder
- Use a variable to refer to the correct folder location (this way you can change it easily if you want, you kan even put in in the settings file)
- Configure your project to automatically copy the json file to the build folder [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374074/copy-files-to-output-directory-using-csproj-dotnetcore)