# Xunit test not copying appsettings file to output directory

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, xunit

I have a Xunit test project that targets both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.6.1. My test loads an appsettings.json file [as detailed by Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Feb/18/Accessing-Configuration-in-NET-Core-Test-Projects). When the test runs, even though I have set the file properties to be of Content type and to always copy to output directory, the file isn't actually there when the test runs.

Now I was successfully able to use this technique in another unit test project, but the difference is that one targets .NET Core 3.1 only. In the working test project, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` is `C:\git\myproject\src\myproject.tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` (i.e., the build output directory). However, in the failing test, the location is `C:\Users\hcheng\AppData\Local\Temp\ffe98278-56d3-41f6-8864-e50c74cb2c08\ffe98278-56d3-41f6-8864-e50c74cb2c08\assembly\dl3\8ba8de87\6b2a96ca_54b8d601` and when I open Windows Explorer to that path, the only contents in that folder are the DLL and the PDB of the unit test project, and `__AssemblyInfo__.ini` (none of the other dependencies are there either).

I'm totally new to .NET Core so I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong, but I suspect that the multi-targeting is related. Since the other dependencies are missing from that temp location, I'm also worried that if I get past this hurdle of loading the config file, I'll still get TypeLoadExceptions afterwards.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer in [How to refer to test files from Xunit tests in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515736/how-to-refer-to-test-files-from-xunit-tests-in-visual-studio).

Instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, I had to use `new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath`.